# Can't use *(asterisk) in commandline process from C# on Mac OS X

Tags: c#, macos, command-line, scp

I'm trying to issue a commandline command via C#'s Process class and I've discovered it won't run correctly if I use an * in the command arguments.  Here's an example:

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "scp",

    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    CreateNoWindow = false,
    Arguments = "<Path>/* " + _remotePath,
    WorkingDirectory = _localPath
};
```

This produces:

`<Path>/*: No such file or directory`

If I remove the * and put in an specific filename like so

`Arguments = "<Path>/file.ext " + _remotePath,`

the command runs successfully.

Comment: It may be that the expansion of the wildcard is done by the shell, and that the scp program actually gets a full list of matching filenames.

Comment: In windows there are no environmental variables (like path) where process is launched.  Try full path name.

Comment: @jdweng I'm on a Mac actually, not Windows.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I think you're right, it must be something to do with the * wildcard.  I'll try looking into what the * produces and maybe generate the file list manually.

Comment: I know.  Did you try full path?

Comment: Well it wasn't a problem where the file couldn't be found because it needed the full path.  It was just that '*' wasn't going through the normal wildcard expansion.  I posted a workaround for anyone else trying to do the same thing.  It's not as convenient, but it worked for me at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the concern that wildcards might not work, I changed it up to just build the file list in C# and pass that whole string to the commandline.  It's not as convenient as passing in '*', but it has the advantage of working :)

```
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(_localPath);
    string fileList = string.Join(" ", filePaths);

    ...

    Arguments = fileList + " " + _remotePath,
```